# Run SSH over a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: ssh, dns, socks

I need VPN-like behavior locally, without using a VPN.

I've created a SOCKS proxy to a given server which is reachable from the WAN, and I want all of my traffic forwarded through that proxy so I can reach hosts inside of that network.

My SOCKS proxy looks like this:

```
ssh -t -D 8088 user@proxy-host 'watch -n 1 date'
```

I've setup my system to proxy though this using the System Settings:

[image]

I've verified that my environment variables are being set properly:

```
naftuli@macbook-nkay:~$ env | grep socks_proxy
socks_proxy=socks://127.0.0.1:8088/
```

However, when I go to SSH to a given server, I can't reach it:

```
$ ssh internal-host
ssh: Could not resolve hostname internal-host: Name or service not known
```

I think that the problem is that DNS isn't being forwarded over the SOCKS tunnel. Is there a way to set that up? I was able to configure Firefox to manually use remote DNS and it worked great. Is there an environment variable for this?

Answer (score 6):

Similar topic was discussed in [SU](https://superuser.com/questions/454210/how-can-i-use-ssh-with-a-socks-5-proxy):

openssh itself doesn't understand the `socks_proxy` environment variables. You need to use for example netcat to direct the traffic over the proxy:

```
 ssh -o ProxyCommand='nc -X 5 --proxy 127.0.0.1:8088 %h %p' user@host
```

To forward DNS requests, it will be more complicated, because low-level functions in openssh do not respect environmental variables. You will probably need to set up your local DNS resolver, which will forward the requests to the proxy. There is [dns-tcp-socks-proxy](https://github.com/jtRIPper/dns-tcp-socks-proxy), which should handle.

```
./dns_proxy --socks_port=8088 --listen_port=53
```

When you will have this daemon running, you should set up the your `/etc/resolv.conf` (hope Mac respects this one) to use this DNS.

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Simple test should be possible using `dig` again, but when this resolver if functional, you will not need the proxy part:

```
dig example.com
```

#### Alternative as jumpbox:

As an easy alternative, I can recommend using normal the host as a jumphost, skip the proxy part and do IO redirect using `-W` switch:

```
ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p jumpbox" destination_host
```

It should do the dns resoving and routing on the jumpbox. This option can be easily incorporated into your `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: Having trouble finding a way to tunnel DNS, Firefox and Chrome can do it, but it seems that OpenSSH can't.

Comment: Yes. I see. Doing single DNS request sounds possible: `dig --socks5 127.0.0.1:8088 @4.2.2.1 example.com`, but forcing to do it on low-level will be more complicated. Still looking into this, since this sounds like nice topic.

Comment: added comments about DNS. Conceptually it should be possible to make it working this way on Linux, so hopefully also on Mac.

Comment: I added possible alternative, that should do the same job without bothering with third party tools but is not using the SOCKS proxy.

Comment: ncat has a command line option: `--proxy-type socks5` which is required to be specified for a SOCKSv5 proxy.