# HOWTO: sshfs via socks proxy

Tags: ssh, sshfs, fuse, socks

I have some bridge host, which allows access to protected network. I connect to it using this command:

```
ssh sergius@bridge_host -D 3128
```

Thus, I can turn on socks proxy in browser and it works. I can login to hosts on that network with this command:

```
ssh -o 'ProxyCommand /bin/nc.openbsd -x localhost:3128 %h %p' sergius@any_internal_host
```

It works properly, but I can't mount via sshfs any of these hosts. Probably, I can't get how to use this ssh options in sshfs command. I tried even so silly tricks:

```
 sshfs -o "ssh_command=\"ssh -o 'ProxyCommand /bin/nc.openbsd -x localhost:3128 %h %p'\"" sergius@$host /home/sergius/work/SSHFS/$host/
 sshfs -o 'SSHOPT=ProxyCommand /bin/nc.openbsd -x localhost:3128 %h %p' sergius@$host: /home/sergius/work/SSHFS/$host/
 sshfs -o 'port=3128' sergius@$host: /home/sergius/work/SSHFS/$host/
```

One command returns "Connection reset by peer", another - unknown option `SSHOPT=ProxyCommand /bin/nc.openbsd -x localhost:3128 %h %p'

I didn't manage to find any info on the web. Please, help.

===

I feel so stupid, but still can't understand why I got such error:

```
 sshfs -d -o sshfs_debug -o LogLevel=DEBUG3 -o ProxyCommand="/bin/nc.openbsd --proxy localhost:3128 --proxy-type socks5 %h %p" sergius@$host:~ /home/sergius/work/SSHFS/$host/
 SSHFS version 2.4
 FUSE library version: 2.9.0
 nullpath_ok: 0
 nopath: 0
 utime_omit_ok: 0
 executing <ssh> <-x> <-a> <-oClearAllForwardings=yes> <-oLogLevel=DEBUG3> <-oProxyCommand=/bin/nc.openbsd --proxy localhost:3128 --proxy-type socks5 %h %p> <-2> <sergius@dev-host003> <-s> <sftp>
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
 debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
 debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /bin/nc.openbsd --proxy localhost:3128 --proxy-type socks5 dev-host003 22
 debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1000
 debug1: identity file /home/sergius/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
 debug1: identity file /home/sergius/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
 debug1: identity file /home/sergius/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
 debug1: identity file /home/sergius/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
 debug1: identity file /home/sergius/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
 debug1: identity file /home/sergius/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
 /bin/nc.openbsd: invalid option -- '-'
 usage: nc [-46bCDdhjklnrStUuvZz] [-I length] [-i interval] [-O length]
     [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port] [-q seconds] [-s source]
     [-T toskeyword] [-V rtable] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_protocol]
     [-x proxy_address[:port]] [destination] [port]
 ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
 read: Connection reset by peer
```

=================

Wow! I managed to make it work!!! Great thanks for clarification with options. I read all allowed options and make it via "-x proxy_adress[:port]":

```
sshfs -o ProxyCommand="/bin/nc.openbsd -x localhost:3128  %h %p" sergius@$host:/home/sergius /home/sergius/work/SSHFS/$host/
```

Comment: I personally used sshfs in the past in servers, not fond of it. I also remember using it via ssh, and not being *that* complicated. I googled around and found this http://www.rdeeson.com/weblog/86/using-ssh-tunnelling-to-access-a-local-network-remotely.htm

Comment: Obviously, your nc doesn't support those --proxy/--proxy-type options

Comment: So, what I should do - update nc? My OS - Debian 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was [answering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244490/121504) similar question not a long time ago. I didn't try it, but this one should work for you:

```
sshfs -o ProxyCommand="/bin/nc.openbsd --proxy localhost:3128 \
  --proxy-type socks5 %h %p" sergius@$host: /home/sergius/work/SSHFS/$host/
```

The `SSHOPT=VAL` just the format of option you want to use. You need to replace it with the specific key-value pair.

Also you need to tell the `nc` what type of proxy is that

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Also - connection reset by peer

Comment: so lets try to debug it with `-d -o sshfs_debug -o LogLevel=DEBUG3` options and post in the edited question full output. Does the proxy work for other traffic?

Comment: With debug enabled: `/bin/nc.openbsd: invalid option -- '-'`. Use `-X proxy_protocol` and `-x proxy_addres`. https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/netcat-openbsd/nc.1.en.html , use: `/bin/nc -X SOCKS5 -x 127.0.0.1:8081 %h %p`

Comment: -o ProxyCommand="nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p"